# Why does it print it all at once?

Tags: python

I am trying to print 1 letter at a time on the same line, but it prints it all at once instead

this is the code I tried:

```
import time
text = ["f", "i", "n", "e"]
x = 0

while x <= 3:
    print(text[0], end="")
    text.remove(text[0])
    x += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Probably `print()` is buffering.

Comment: Why are you modifying `text` in-place instead of simply iterating over it? `for c in text: print(c, end=""); time.sleep(1)`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what does that mean?

Comment: @chepner that doesn't work

Comment: It's not a fix for the buffering issue.

Comment: See the full answers below

Answer (score 3):

Standard output is line-buffered by default: nothing is actually written to standard output until a full line has been printed. You need to flush each character explicitly, most simply with the `flush` keyword argument.

```
for c in text:
    print(c, end="", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `print()` buffers. This means that it stores characters in memory rather than sending each character to output. This makes printing much more efficient because sending data to output takes a lot of time.

You can force `print()` to output immediately by setting `flush=True`:

```
print(text[0], end="", flush=True)
```

You should also iterate over the text directly:

```
import time
text = "fine"

for c in text
    print(c, end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```